# Return all in List <T> in lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I'm using lambda expression in LINQ where i have to get all the result when the conditon satisfies if not it should filter.

//Code

```
 List<Dispatch> objDispatch = (List<Dispatch>)Session["Data"];
objDispatch = objDispatch.FindAll(dispatch => dispatch.CustomerTransName == ddlTransporterName.SelectedItem.Text && dispatch.InvoiceDate.Date >= Convert.ToDateTime(FromDate).Date && dispatch.InvoiceDate.Date <= Convert.ToDateTime(ToDate).Date);
```

In the above code i'm filtering the result set with some conditions in that first condition i need a help.

If the transporter name is 'ALL' it should return all the result set it matches with the Date condition or else it should return according to the TransporterName.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Just a quick note - you're not using LINQ at all here. `List<T>.FindAll` was part of `List<T>` in .NET 2.0.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you want the list to return all the objects with a date between two dates if the selected item in the drop-down list is `"ALL"`, otherwise it should filter on the name as well as the date? A simple `if` should suffice if this is the case.

Comment: @Sean: If the dropdown list is 'All' i need all the records, if not it should filter.

Comment: Does the date filter need to be applied all the time, or only when the selected item is not "All"?

Comment: @EliArbel: Lambda expressions are widely applicable beyond LINQ. I'd say they *contribute* to LINQ, but if using a lambda expression counts as using LINQ, that's a pretty wide scope, which includes uses which have *nothing* to do with querying.

Comment: @EliArbel: I guess we'll have to agree to differ. If the OP had used an anonymous method instead, so that the code would have run as-is in .NET 2, would you still say it counts as LINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pure logic.

```
if(ddlTransporterName.SelectedItem.Text == "ALL") {
  //return all
} else {
  //Do your filter logic
}
```

Or, with less repitive code:

```
objDispatch = objDispatch.FindAll(
  dispatch => (ddlTransporterName.SelectedItem.Text == "ALL" || dispatch.CustomerTransName == ddlTransporterName.SelectedItem.Text) 
  && dispatch.InvoiceDate.Date >= Convert.ToDateTime(FromDate).Date 
  && dispatch.InvoiceDate.Date <= Convert.ToDateTime(ToDate).Date);
```

Comment: Wrong condition `dispatch.CustomerTransName == "ALL"` that will check names. OP want to skip checking names if transporter name is `ALL`

Answer (score 2):

```
string name = ddlTransporterName.SelectedItem.Text;
objDispatch = objDispatch.FindAll(dispatch => 
   (name == "ALL" || dispatch.CustomerTransName == name) 
   && dispatch.InvoiceDate.Date >= Convert.ToDateTime(FromDate).Date 
   && dispatch.InvoiceDate.Date <= Convert.ToDateTime(ToDate).Date);
```

If transporter name is "ALL" then name OR condition will give `true` and `CustomerTransName` will not be checked.

Answer (score 2):

If you want this to be LINQ then you need to actually use a LINQ method e.g. use `Where`. Also you should do your date conversions once outside if they aren't specific to the row, otherwise they will be converting everytime. Not only that, it makes for more readable code...

```
var selectedTransporter = ddlTransporterName.SelectedItem.Text;
var fromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(FromDate).Date;
var toDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ToDate).Date;
var query = objDispatch.Where(x => (selectedTransporter == "All" || x.CustomerTransName == selectedTransporter) && x.InvoiceDate.Date >= fromDate && x.InvoiceDate.Date <= toDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should suffice:

```
List<Dispatch> objDispatch = (List<Dispatch>)Session["Data"];

List<Dispatch> filteredDispatches = objDispatch.Where(dispatch => dispatch.InvoiceDate.Date >= Convert.ToDateTime(FromDate).Date && dispatch.InvoiceDate.Date <= Convert.ToDateTime(ToDate).Date).ToList();

if (ddlTransporterName.SelectedItem.Text != "ALL")
{
    filteredDispatches = filteredDispatches.Where(dispatch => dispatch.CustomerTransName == ddlTransporterName.SelectedItem.Text).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work:

```
List<Dispatch> objDispatch = (List<Dispatch>)Session["Data"];

var _fromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(FromDate);
var _toDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ToDate);

objDispatch = objDispatch
    .FindAll(dispatch => Selector(
         dispatch, ddlTransporterName.SelectedItem.Text, _fromDate, _toDate));

static bool Selector(
    Dispatch dispatch, string name, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
    if (dispatch.CustomerTransName == "ALL")
    {
        return dispatch.InvoiceDate.Date >= fromDate.Date
            && dispatch.InvoiceDate.Date <= toDate.Date;
    }

    return dispatch.CustomerTransName == name;
}
```